# Adding items to a Linux kernel linked list

Tags: c, list, linux-kernel

I am using `linux/list.h` in my code for implementing queue/stack behavior. The API for adding at head/tail is as below:

```
static inline void list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
         __list_add(new, head, head->next);
}
```

Similar is for `list_add_tail`. Surprisingly, it returns nothing (`void`), so does it mean that addition to list in kernel using this API is always successful. I know that there is no concept of *full* here but what if memory allocation for new node is not available and other possible reasons?

Comment: You may also refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850930/correct-way-to-join-two-double-linked-list/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `list` API does not dynamically allocate any memory.  I found this thing a bit puzzling, myself.  Problem here is that Linux is written in C, not C++, but implements things in a quite object-oriented way, but in C it looks like inside out.  It works as follows (this applies to several other Linux APIs, too, e.g. `kobj`):

You define some `struct`, which should be member of a list.  In opposite of how you would usually think of linked lists, this object won't be put into the list by allocating some opaque list item and have a pointer pointing to your actual object, you make `struct list_head` an actual a *member* of your `struct`:

```
struct something {
    struct list_head list;
    uint8_t some_datum;
    uint16_t some_other_datum;
    void *a_pointer;
};
```

Your list will be some *standalone* `struct list_head`:

```
static LIST_HEAD(list_of_somethings);
```

To add elements to `list_of_somethings` you now would do something like

```
struct something *s = kmalloc(sizeof(*s), GFP_KERNEL);
s->some_datum = 23;
s->some_other_datum = 0xdeadbeef;
s->a_pointer = current;
list_add(&s->list, &list_of_somethings);
```

In other words, you have the element allocated already.  This looks completely weird, but is elegant as f*ck.  This "design-pattern" allows to have type-opaque lists in C, which would not be easy to do in another way: A list on its own is just a bunch of `struct list_head`s pointing to each other.  As you know which actual `struct` you are expeting as a programmer, you know which element of this `struct` is the actual `list_head` and can use the `container_of` macro to get the pointer to the eventual `struct` you put into the list:

```
struct list_head *p = &list_of_somethings.next;
struct something *s = container_of(p, struct something, list);
pr_notice("some data = %i\n", s->some_data);
```

Notice that the actual `struct list_head` representing the list itself is handled specially by the iteration macros defined in `<linux/list.h>`, i.e.

```
#define list_for_each(pos, head) \
        for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); pos = pos->next)
```

The address of `list_of_somethings` will be used to determine whether iterating reached the end of the list (or actually the list-object again).
This is also the reason, why an empty list is defined as having `next` and `prev` point to the `struct list_head` itself.

I needed some time to wrap my head around this, too. ;)

Comment: Thanks Andreas for elaborate explanation. I had completely missed that point that I've already allocated node containing list_head in it. Anyways your answer gave me lot more information.

Comment: Great answer, but why do you pass `head` which is already `&list_of_somethings.next` to `list_for_each` which starts from `pos=(head)->next`? Wouldn't we miss the first element? I guess the correct thing would be to pass `&list_of_somethings` as `head` to the `list_for_each`.

Comment: It's simply the list's semantic, as I tried to express in the last paragraph: the "first" element of the list usually isn't part of the list but only a sole `struct list_head` holding the list (i.e. some `struct list_head`-typed member of another superordinate object containing this list).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all the memory has been allocated by you at that point, so all it's really doing is hooking up the pointers which are already allocated.

The memory is already there, all it's doing is filling it in so there isn't any real way it can fail.