# How to transverse a linked list in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, linux-kernel

So I have a linked list in c. I'm trying to compile it using a module in Linux. So in my linked list, I'm entering 6 people. With there month, day and year and name. In the program, I've entered 6 people and there attributes. When I try to transverse the linked list it's not compiling correctly. My code is almost done but doesn't know exactly where I'm messing up on.

Error messages I'm getting:

```
 implicit declartion of funciton 'print'
    assignment from incompatible pointer type
    expected ; before while
    ISO c90 forbids mixed declarations and code
    expected expression before',' token
    'next' undeclared
    invalid type argument of unary '*"

compiling through terminal and the erro i'm getting are: warning control reaches end non-void function. – black 7 mins ago   

Expted declaration or statement at end of input. – black 7 mins ago   

in expantion of macro 'Module_License – black 6 mins ago   

warning 'alias' attribute ignored. – black 5 mins ago   

Error: invalid storage class for function – black 5 mins ago   

error: expected identifier before '=' token *birthday_list->NULL; – black 5 mins ago   

error: struct birthday has no member named next – black 4 mins ago   edit           
You have a lot of mistake in your code such as ptr=&birthday_list (forgot semicolon in the end of the line. – ymonad just now
```

So I'm trying to get it to where the output is:
[It loads the module and states the six people then removes the people in the list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUBp1.png)

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

struct birthday 
{   
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    char *name;

    struct list_head list;  
};

/**
 * The following defines and initializes a list_head object named birthday_list
 */
static LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);

int simple_init(void)
{
    struct birthday *person;
    /* Creating Person 1 */
    person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    person->month = 8;
    person->day = 12;
    person->year = 1993;
    person->name = "Aaron";
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

    /* Creating Person 2 */
    person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    person->month = 4;
    person->day = 15;
    person->year = 1993;
    person->name = "Fish";

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);
    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

    /* Creating Person 3 */
    person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    person->month = 3;
    person->day = 29;
    person->year = 1983;
    person->name = "js";

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);
    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

    /* Creating Person 4 */
    person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    person->month = 7;
    person->day = 25;
    person->year = 1999;
    person->name = "Mark";

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);
    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

    /* Creating Person 5 */
    person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    person->month = 7;
    person->day = 19;
    person->year = 1992;
    person->name = "Leah";

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);
    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

    /* Creating Person 6 */
    person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    person->month = 1;
    person->day = 11;
    person->year = 1991;
    person->name = "Han";

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);
    list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");

    struct birthday *ptr;
    list_for_each_entry(ptr, &birthday_list, list) {
        /* On each iteration ptr points */
        /* to the next birthday struct  */
if(ptr ==NULL){
print("List is empty");
}else{
ptr=&birthday_list
while(ptr!=NULL){
ptr=ptr->list;
}
}


    return 0;
}

void simple_exit(void) {

    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Module\n");
    struct birthday *ptr, *next

    list_for_each_entry_safe(ptr, next, *birthday_list, list) {
while(ptr!=NULL){
ptr->next=*birthday_list->next;
*birthday_list->=NULL;
}
        list_del(&ptr->list);
        kfree(ptr);
    }   
}

module_init(simple_init);
module_exit(simple_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Kernel Data Structures");
MODULE_AUTHOR("SGG");
```

Comment: How are you compiling, and what is the error message?

Comment: compiling through terminal and the erro i'm getting are: warning control reaches end non-void function.

Comment: Expted declaration or statement at end of input.

Comment: in expantion of macro 'Module_License

Comment: warning 'alias' attribute ignored.

Comment: Error: invalid storage class for function

Comment: error: expected identifier before '=' token *birthday_list->NULL;

Comment: error: struct birthday has no member named next

Comment: You should paste the error message in the question, not as comment.

Comment: In your question under section "Error messages I'm getting:" you get a TRASH, like `black 6 mins ago`. Copy **actual** error message from the compiler's output, paste it into the question post and format as a code.

Comment: I think 'print' don't exist in kernel space, also a ';' is missing here : `ptr=&birthday_list`

Comment: You can check this answer as well to see a picture of linked lists in kernel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850930/correct-way-to-join-two-double-linked-list/33853454#33853454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- In the second line of the `simple_exit` function you forgot the `;` at the end of the line.
- In the `simple_exit` function you have the line `ptr->next=*birthday_list->next;` where `ptr` is a pointer onto a `struct birthday` object. Unfortunately, `struct birthday` objects have no `next` member.
- In the `simple_exit` function you have the line `*birthday_list->=NULL;` which is just wrong syntax-wise. Did you want to write `birthday_list = NULL;` or something similar?
- At the end of the `simple_init` function you use `print` instead of `printk`.
- Your compiler complains that `ISO c90 forbids mixed declarations and code`. This basically means that if you use a compiler that adheres to the C90 standard you must declare all your variables before you do "anything else". So stuff like

  ```
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  i = i + 5;
  ```

  works while

  ```
  int i = 0;
  i = i + 5;
  int j = 0;
  ```

  does not because `j` was declared after "something was done with `i`". You do similar things in your code, for example you declare `struct birthday *ptr;` in the middle of the `simple_init` function. In this case you should move this line to the beginning of the `simple_init` function.

There might be some more issues in the code but you may try to fix these issues first. It is also a good idea to read the error messages carefully as they are somtimes self-explanatory.