# Unexpected result when using container_of macro (Linux kernel)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a problem with using of `container_of` macro in the Linux kernel. I have the following code

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member) *__mptr = (ptr); \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type, member) );})


struct list_head
{
    struct list_head *prev;
    struct list_head *next;
};


struct fox
{
    unsigned long tail_length;
    unsigned long weight;
    unsigned int is_fantastic;

    /*Make this struct a node of the linked list*/
    struct list_head list;
};
```

I want to make fox structure a node of the linked list.

```
int main(void)
{
    struct list_head node_first = {.prev=NULL, .next=NULL};
    struct fox first_f = {.tail_length=3, .weight=4, .is_fantastic=0, .list=node_first};

    struct fox *second_f; 
    second_f = container_of(&node_first, struct fox, list);
    printf("%lu\n", second_f->tail_length);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that I will see `3` in the terminal, since `second_l` points to the `firstf_f` structure, but I have `140250641491552` (some "random" value from the memory, as a think).

Comment: You're using `container_of_s()`, which is not `container_of()`. Is that a typo?

Comment: You really have to read what is written in the comments in the *include/linux/list.h*. You are barely doing a thing right. To understand what linked list is in Linux kernel, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850930/correct-way-to-join-two-double-linked-list

Answer (score 3):

That's not how `offsetof` is meant to be used. Your supposed to pass a pointer to data held in a struct to retrieve a pointer to the overall struct (So a `struct list_head**`). Instead you pass a copy of a pointer to the wrong value (`&node_first` is different to `&first_f.list` (what you're supposed to pass), as it is a copy)

For an example of how it works, consider this `struct list_head` object:

```
(struct list_head) {   // At 0x1000
    .prev = 0,  // At 0x1000
    .next = 0   // At 0x1004
}
```

If you were to call `container_of((struct list_head**) 0x1004, struct list_head, next)`, you would get `(struct list_head*) 0x1000`.

This example is a bit confusing because of the same types, so here's another example:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member) *__mptr = (ptr); \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type, member) );})

struct holds_values {
    int n;
    char c;
};

struct holds_values* get_container(char* c_ptr) {
    // If this was a pointer to a `c` in `holds_values`
    // e.g., `&object.c`, that `char` is sizeof(int) bytes into
    // the object, so this should be mostly the same as
    // `(struct holds_values*) (c - sizeof(int))`
    return container_of(c_ptr, struct holds_values, c);
}

int main() {
    struct holds_values x = { .n = 5, .c = 'a' };

    char* ptr = &x.c;
    struct holds_values* y = get_container(ptr);
    printf("%d\n%d\n", y == &x, y->n);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will my code work if i will pass the node to yhe structure by pointer? I mean, that in the structure definition will be declared: struct list_head *list and .list = &node_first when initializing fox structure?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
second_f = container_of(&node_first, struct fox, list);
```

to

```
second_f = container_of(&first_f.list, struct fox, list);
```

**Explanation**:

This has nothing to do with kernel or Linux, it's C and GCC.

The line

```
struct fox first_f = {.tail_length=3, .weight=4, .is_fantastic=0, .list=node_first};
```

copies the contents of `node_first` into `first_f.list`. `first_f` is NOT the container of `node_first`, it contains a *copy of* `node_first`.

If you want `first_f` to be the container of `node_first` you need to define:

```
struct fox first_f = {.tail_length=3, .weight=4, .is_fantastic=0, .list={.prev=NULL, .next=NULL}};
struct list_head *node_first = &first_f.list;
```

i.e. define `node_first` as a pointer into the member of `first_f`.

Note that you *could* define `struct fox` to have

```
struct fox
{
    // ...
    struct list_head *list;
};
```

instead of

```
struct fox
{
    // ...
    struct list_head list;
};
```

i.e. to have `struct fox` *point* to the `list_head`, and then your original `main()` would work.

But that's simply not the right way to use `list_head`, `list_head` is intended to be contained within other structs.